# Backup tool for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup software for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/375/backup-software-for-mac-os-x)

Hello there I'm lookng for a good way to  backup my files on Mac Os.
I know there is time machine but it keeps saving lots of changes happening on the same file while all I want is to be able to save my data as is(one instance) is there a way to do that in time machine or should I use another tool?
Thanks

Comment: You could use TimeMachine but leave it unplugged most of the time...

Comment: sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-auto StartInterval -int 1800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For backing up to a  **local** disk try [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/).  CCC allows you to make bootable backups, and tracks incremental changes (which sounds important to you).  It isn't a Time Machine replacement though as far as I can tell, as it doesn't allow you to go back and recover older historical versions of files.

For a **remote** backup try [Crash Plan](http://b2.crashplan.com/consumer/).  Allows for backup to a remote computer, or to the CrashPlan remote storage (for a fee).  It runs in the background so you're constantly backed up, and does versioning sort of like TimeMachine.  However, you don't need to worry about how much storage you're actually using by the versioning if you're using their remote storage solution.

Comment: It's been a lot of time since the answer but I did use crash plan free edition and it feels great!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself but I have heard a lot of positive things about [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/superduper/superduperdescription.html).

Answer (score 1):

I like `rsync`. Doesn't quite fit into the OS X UI though...

Comment: No, but for that, there's arSync.