# How can I make a full backup of OS X?

Tags: macos, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup software for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/375/backup-software-for-mac-os-x)

I just installed OS X. I'd like to make a full backup to restore my OS later.

In Windows, I used Windows Backup to do this. What can I use in Mac OS X?

Comment: @Gareth // why not? it is still Mac OS

Comment: And don't complain if anything doesn't work or if you won't be able to restore.

Comment: For the record, I voted to closed as "Off-topic", not as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Buy an external hard drive larger than your internal hard drive with the OS and files. Use [Time Machine](http://tonymacx86.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5979), the built-in backup solution from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time using superduper. You can clone to any hardrive or partition that is HSF+ formatted and large enough. You can then boot off the copy if the original fails. For a Hackintosh you also need to intall your boot software (I use chameleon) to the hardrive if you want to be able to boot from it.